# How to format y tick label into a consistent decimal style in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have this plots [image: here].

It is generated by the `pgfplots` code at the bottom. For the y tick labels, instead of the one shown in the figure, I would like to have `{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}` by the y ticks, and a `$10^{-2}$` on top of y axis, just like Jake's [solution to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46750/3690), which produces a figure with the desired y tick label format. (However, this does not do so for my `ytick={0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1}`) [image: here]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=1,
xmin=0,
xmax=6,
ymin=0,
ytick={0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1},
xlabel={X}, ylabel={Y},
yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}]
\addplot [black,thick] table [row sep=crcr]{
0 0\\
2 0.15\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `scaled y ticks=base 10:2` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}    

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
\begin{axis}[
minor tick num=1,
xmin=0,
xmax=6,
ymin=0,
ytick={0.02, 0.04, 0.06, 0.08, 0.1},
xlabel={X}, ylabel={Y},
yticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick},
scaled y ticks=base 10:2
]
\addplot [black,thick] table [row sep=crcr]{
0 0\\
2 0.15\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: **scaled y ticks=base 10:2** is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the quick response.