# Constant number of decimal places EXCEPT 0

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am working with pgfplots and I want a constant number of decimal places on ticks.
A similiar question was answered here [pgfplot with constant decimal places on ticks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46747/pgfplot-with-constant-decimal-places-on-ticks)

```
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable,tikz}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.external}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usetikzlibrary{spy}
\tikzset{mark size=3}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{ tick label style={font=\Large,color=black}, label style={font=\Large,color=black}, legend style={font=\Large},yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,/pgf/number format/precision=3}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={  thick,tick style={ thick},color=black}}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={ thick}} 

\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/every axis x label/.append style={font=\Large,anchor=north}}
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/every axis y label/.append style={font=\Large,anchor=near ticklabel}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,fixed zerofill,precision=2,/tikz/.cd},
scaled ticks=false,xlabel={$x$},ylabel=$y$,xmin=0,xmax=1,
y label style={at={(axis description cs:-0.05,0.5)}}]

\addplot+[error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit,] [only marks,mark=o,black] table [x=x,y=y] {Daten.txt};
\addplot [dotted,black] table [x=x_Daten_Linie,y=y_Daten] {Daten.txt};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My question is: How can I apply this, Except the 0 ?
i.e. I don't want 0.00 when I got 2 decimal places. Just "0".

[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: That's exactly the way to do it, but what can you not achieve with that answer?

Comment: EDTI: I added a Screenshot in the question. At the "0" tick there are several digits "0.000". I just want "0" without decimal places.

Comment: A workaround would be deleting the numbers in Adobe Acrobat Pro, but I don`t think this is a really good solution...

Comment: Do you have the code for that screenshot?

Comment: Added it in the Edit :)

Comment: Please make your code example compilable. Missed are `\documentclass ...` and table ` Daten.txt`.

Comment: I found the exact duplicate for your question, you can ping me here (using @Alenanno) if you think it doesn't work.